# Nginx virtual host setup fine from public, 503 error from the server

Tags: nginx, local, 503-error

I have a VPS with NGINX virtual hosts. The virtual hosts all appear to be fine from public access.

However, I've recently noticed that I get Wordpress errors related to API access and loopback being broken.

All API calls from public seem to be fine.

When I try to access any url from the VPS itself using curl / wget, I just get "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable", though the same url is fully available to the public.

I can't see anything in the vhost or nginx error logs.

I've tried deactivating all plugins and using a default unedited theme, same problems.

I've got around 40 small/med sites virtually hosted on this server, all look like they have the same issues.

I assume it's something in my nginx config, but I've been scouring the internet for hours with no luck. I'd love some pointers, if available!!!

Comment: Read your nginx error log.

Comment: Enable seperate access logs and error logs for that VirtualHost. Also provide the vhost config redacted

Comment: I also found this, please double check with your configuration https://github.com/AbhishekGhosh/Nginx-PHP5-FPM/tree/master/nginx-plus